# Span Image or Display object across two canvas in Flex/as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flex3

My Requirement given below:
  I want to span same image across two canvas.
  Like I have HBOX with two canvas as childs. I want to drag first canvas
  display object into second canvas with half portion of that object in 1st canvas     and half in second canvas.

Thanks in advance if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your image, after dropping it, using, for example, [`copyPixels()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels()) on the `BitmapData` of your image.

Take this example where I used two images in two `Group`s :

```
<s:VGroup x="0" y="0" width="300" height="500">
    <s:Group id="group_top" width="200" height="200" >
        <s:Image id="img_top" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" 
                 source="assets/image.jpg" 
                 mouseDown="img_top_mouseDownHandler(event)"
                 mouseUp="img_top_mouseUpHandler(event)"/>
    </s:Group>
    <s:Group id="group_bottom" width="200" height="200" >   
        <s:Image id="img_bottom" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" source=""/>
    </s:Group>
</s:VGroup>
```

For the dragging and dropping, I used the old `startDrag()` and `stopDrag()` just for the example of course, you may need to use another way according to your needs.

```
protected function img_top_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    img_top.startDrag();
}

protected function img_top_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{   
    img_top.stopDrag();
    img_top.x = img_top.y = 0;              

    split_image();
}
```

And to split the image, I did like this :

```
protected function split_image():void
{
    var bitmap_data_source:BitmapData = img_top.bitmapData;
    var w:int = bitmap_data_source.width,
        h:int = bitmap_data_source.height;

    var bitmap_data_top:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h);
    bitmap_data_top.copyPixels(
        bitmap_data_source, 
        new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h/2), 
        new Point()
    );

    var bitmap_data_bottom:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h);
    bitmap_data_bottom.copyPixels(
        bitmap_data_source, 
        new Rectangle(0, h/2, w, h/2),
        new Point()
    );

    var bitmap_top:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap_data_top);
    img_top.source = bitmap_top;

    var bitmap_bottom:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap_data_bottom);
    img_bottom.source = bitmap_bottom;
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Hi akmozo, copy pixel not useful in my case, Same image component in both canvas same time and other operation like draging,rototion and other  transform and filters, selection handles on both image at same time.Also have option display same image on other page or not.